# Alfresco Data Lists and E-Mail notification

Tags: email, alfresco

I have created a custom Data List and now I would like to send a notification every time that a record is created or updated. The thing is that I would like to include the information inside the record in the e-mail body and I have no idea how. I tried with rules but I can not add the information of the record to the e-mail. Some ideas about it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Rule on the datalist container folder + custom email template?

Answer (score 2):

You can create policy which will fired when you user is creating node of particular type of datalist.

Take below example

Node inside data list is of type **"dl:customNode"** Than create policy which implements **OnCreateNodePolicy**(This will be only called when user is creating node of type "dl:customNode")

Inside Write your code to send mail notification.You can inject your required services in same.